Portainer failed to deploy a stack: docker-compose.yml: no such file or directory
I try switch my Portainer.io deploy from "web editor" to "repository". But I cannot deploy it.

I'm sure that repo name is correct and I have access to it (if I change value under textbox "Repository URL" I receive another error, so I'm sure that this repo exist and user have access to it.

Please note that by default Portainer looks for a .yml file and not a .yaml file

